# How to create multi line cells in xlsx with openpyxl?

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, openpyxl

I have the following data:

`test.json` file

```
{
    "entries": [
        {
            "attributes": {
                "sAMAccountName": "wonder-woman",
                "memberOf": [
                    "woman",
                    "dc-comics",
                    "justice-league",
                    "human"
                ]
            },
            "dn": "CN=Diana Troy,OU=Users,OU=DC-COMICS,DC=universum,DC=local"
        }
    ]
}
```

`excl.json` file

```
{
    "sAMAccountName": [
        "ironman"
    ],
    "dnsHostName": [
        "dell"
    ]
}
```

I am trying to export it into an Excel file by code:

```
import json
from datetime import datetime
from openpyxl import Workbook

encoded_retrieved_users = './test.json'
accounts_excluded = './excl.json

with open(accounts_excluded, 'r', encoding="UTF-8") as file:
    excluded_accounts = json.load(file)
    excluded_users = excluded_accounts['sAMAccountName']

with open(encoded_retrieved_users, 'r', encoding="UTF-8") as file:
    data = json.load(file)
    retrieved_users = data['entries']
retrieved_users.sort(key=lambda d: d["attributes"]["sAMAccountName"])

def user_validation(suspect):
    account = True
    for account_checked in excluded_users:
        if (account_checked == suspect):
            account = False
    return account

A = 'sAMAccountName'
B = 'memberOf'

# Set worksheet
wb = Workbook() # create excel worksheet
ws_01 = wb.active # Grab the active worksheet
ws_01.title = "all inf" # Set the title of the worksheet
# Set first row
row =1
ws_01.cell(row, 1, A) # cell(row, col, value)
ws_01.cell(row, 2, B)
# Set rest rows
row = 2
for user in retrieved_users:
    attributes = user['attributes']
    sAMAccountName = attributes['sAMAccountName']
    if(user_validation(sAMAccountName) == True):
        A = str(sAMAccountName)
        ws_01.cell(row, 1, A)
        for group_name in attributes['memberOf']:
            B = group_name 
            ws_01.cell(row, 2, B)

# Save it in an Excel file
wb.save('./excel.xlsx)
```

However I would like that between each list-element a line break is entered, similar to ALT-ENTER in Excel. So at the end, the excel would look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `wrap_text` *parameter* in [`openpyxl.styles.alignment`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/openpyxl.styles.alignment.html) module.

```
import json
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Alignment

# --- Reading .json files
with open("test.json") as json_enteries:
    data1 = json.load(json_enteries)

with open("excl.json") as json_exclusions:
    data2 = json.load(json_exclusions)

# --- Intersecting the two .json files
excluded_sAMAccountName, excluded_dnsHostName = set(data2.get("sAMAccountName",[])), set(data2.get("dnsHostName",[]))

items = [entry for entry in data1["entries"]
         if entry["attributes"].get("sAMAccountName") not in excluded_sAMAccountName
         or entry["attributes"].get("dnsHostName") not in excluded_dnsHostName]

# --- Creating the WB/WS
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
ws.title = "all inf"

ws.append(["sAMAccountName", "memberOf"])

for idx, entry in enumerate(items, start=1):
    ws.append([entry["attributes"]["sAMAccountName"], "\n".join(entry["attributes"]["memberOf"])])
    cell_value = ws.cell(row=idx+1,column=1).value
    ws.cell(row=idx+1,column=2).alignment = Alignment(wrap_text=True)

ws.column_dimensions["B"].width = 15
ws.column_dimensions["A"].width = 20

wb.save("final.xlsx")
```

Output (*Excel*) :

[image]